# Any good resources for, or examples of, good ways to present 'new user tips'?

Tags: help, tooltips, novice-users

Launching the beta version of a new web app shortly and want to provide a small number of new user tips that will appear one at a time the first 5-10 times a user logs on. I'm looking for some best practices or great examples of tips like these.

FYI, the tips would be oriented around helping users get the most out of the site and would be displayed at the top of the screen. The content would be along the lines of reminders to fill out profiles, invite FB friends, and other things of that nature. In addition, they would explain why taking this particular action would help.

For context, the site is a web app that helps user connect with their friends and our community in order to help them get a second opinion on potential apparel and accessory purchases.

Comment: Funnily enough Stack Exchange have just [removed their "New User" message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122428/59303).

Answer (score 2):

I personally was a big fan of how Google used to have the yellow notification horizontal bar at the top when something had changed in their interface.I find it pretty useful since it was eye catching but not intrusive and people could always hide it needed.

Comment: Thanks for sending along an answer! I remember that actually. I wish I could add pictures to show what I have now, because it's somewhat along those lines, but unfortunately my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: You could upload it to tiny url or something like that and post the link in the comments